# Attempt to start android fails - tools need to be updated or installed

Tags: android, installation

I see this on the forum, but unlike the hit on the forum where a version update was required to resolve, I believe my software is up to date.

Under Windows 7, Android SDK Manager shows:

android sdk tools 21.1 Installed

Android sdk platform tools 16.0.2 Installed

SDK path c:\users\owner\documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk

When I try to begin a project via 'file-new-Android Application Project', the panel reports

---The tools need to be updated via the SDK Manager

---Tools installed out of date or not installed

Any direction on this would be appreciated.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to Help->Check for Updates

Answer (score 0):

```
OK. I had viewed this Eclipse ADT and find out the way to get around this issue and able to Update My SDK Tool to 21.1.0.

Solution is : First Update ADT to 21.1.0 and Then Update SDK Tool to 21.1.0

Actually, above link Says,

ADT 21.1.0 is designed for use with SDK Tools r21.1.0. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r21.1.0 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so.

So, What i have to do is to update my ADT to 21.1.0(Latest Version) and then was able to update SDK tool to 21.1.0. i thought only SDK Tool has been updated Not ADT. so i was Updating the SDK Tool with Older ADT Version(21.0.1).

How to Update your ADT to Latest Version?

In Eclipse go to Help
Install New Software ---> Add
inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (as you want)
and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
after loading some time you will get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
check both if you want to use NDK in the future or check Developer Tool only
click Next
Finish

Copied
```

Comment: On sdk manager, it shows both 'Android SDK tools 2.1.1 installed' as well as 'Android SDK Platform-Tools 16.0.2 installed'. Should both be listed? SDK manager is successfully finding the path to the sdk\tools directory, and I see that the files in it are mostly dated 02/2013 so I am confident that sdk manager is pointing to the latest tools directory. But I continue to get the message that tools need to be updated or are out of date or not installed.

Comment: Try that part of install new software ,because sometimes they need to be updated ,it will show you what u need

Comment: I have used 'install new software' and it shows all items installed for 'SDK Tools', Revision 21 - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/',

Comment: I have used 'install new software' and it shows all items installed for both 'Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/' and for 'SDK Tools, Revision 21 - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/'. I think I will use my other system, a linux system, and try to install and run eclipse/android there. Sincere thanks for all your help.